# Regarding Generalized Products of Cosines

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I was looking at this identity (see below) from Wikipedia, and I don't quite understand how you can add and multiply elements from $S$. Elements of $S$ are sequences of -1's and 1's, so how are arithmetic operations defined? Or am I misunderstanding the notation? Could someone give an example of how this sum is carried out for, let's say, n=4?

\begin{align*} 
\prod_{k=1}^n \cos \theta_k & = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{e\in S} \cos(e_1\theta_1+\cdots+e_n\theta_n) 
\end{align*}
where $S=\{1,-1\}^n$.

Also, is there any deeper meaning to this identity, or is it just a result of algebraic/geometric acrobatics?

Comment: Would this have been clearer? $$\prod_{k=1}^n \cos \theta_k = \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{e_i=\pm1} \cos(e_1\theta_1+\cdots+e_n\theta_n) 
$$ The sum is over all sequences of $1$s and $-1$s, so its the sum of $\cos\theta$ over all $\theta$-values that are sums of $\pm\theta_j$ with every possible combination of pluses and minuses.

Comment: @SteveKass Ah yes, this makes perfect sense, thank you!